# Do you know why its showing undefined array key \"option\""

Tags: php

Do you know why `dd(request());` shows this:

```
array:1 [
  "content" => array:8 [
    "title" => "test"
    "description" => "desc"
    "option" => "2"
```

But then trying to show the value of the option key like this:

```
    dd(request(['content']['option']));
```

Shows an errror:

> message: "Undefined array key "option""

Comment: It should be `request()['content']['option']`.

Comment: But with             request()['content']['option'] ? request()['content']['option'] : 5 it shows ""Trying to access array offset on value of type null"" but request()['content']['option'] shows 2.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://3v4l.org/EiFap). What if you store the result of `request()` in a variable first? Maybe request() return a different value in each call?